# preset checkbox statement in flask

Tags: flask, checkbox, preset

I'm trying to make checkbox checked in template if some_condition == True
That's how it looks

`{{ form.country_ru(checked="checked" if some_condition else "") }}`

but it is always checked, even if some_condition == False
Why?
How to make it work right?